# SliverPersistentHeader nested in Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I build a SliverPersistentHeader with delegate, if I scroll down the searchbar is pinned to top.

Now I want to add Text above the searchbar which should not be pinned at all.
But somehow I need to group the text and searchbar, because I want them to have the **same gradient background.**

If I scroll down only the searchbar should be pinned, the text should be scrolled out of view.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

`SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate` has a `minExtent` and `maxExtent` and its `build`-method's `shrinkOffset` parameter tells you where the actual extent is between `minExtent` and `maxExtent` (it's `maxExtent - actualExtent`). That should be enough to achieve what you want.